# Angular 13 NG0301 error does not show module giving error

Tags: angular

Could you please assist me?

I upgraded my Angular project from v11 to v13:

```
Angular: 13.2.4
... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1302.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular   13.2.5
@angular-devkit/core            13.2.5
@angular-devkit/schematics      13.2.5
@angular/cli                    13.2.5
@schematics/angular             9.1.15
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.5.5
```

I was able to run my project successfully.

I then tried the following on a parent controller:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
```

I then deleted that import.

I now get the following console error when I try to run my project:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG0301
Error: NG0301
    at fO (main.js:1:57364)
    at xm (main.js:1:57397)
    at TA (main.js:1:69323)
    at l (main.js:1:69467)
    at template (main.js:1:444680)
    at N1 (main.js:1:53378)
    at Oc (main.js:1:51511)
    at wO (main.js:1:59577)
    at tO (main.js:1:51715)
    at Oc (main.js:1:51726)
    at ue (polyfills.js:1:137893)
    at ue (polyfills.js:1:137404)
    at polyfills.js:1:138755
    at S.invokeTask (polyfills.js:1:128526)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main.js:1:105006)
    at S.invokeTask (polyfills.js:1:128447)
    at S.runTask (polyfills.js:1:123566)
    at P (polyfills.js:1:130871)
```

I have checked online and most NG0301 errors usually mention the module that is giving the issue.  But in my case, I do not get this.

Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

Comment: It is easier to debug in the non compiled js files.

Comment: I had the same error without any reason I was able to find. When upgrading Angular to version 13, it now enables by default the caching functionalities. I don't really know why, but deleting the `.angular/cache` folder and `ng serve` again solved the issue! Give it a try.

Answer (score 8):

I was also getting same error, So resolved it by deleting `cache` folder in `.angular`.

```
rm .angular/cache
ng serve
```

Comment: Aah, this helped...probably not the right thing to do but oh well :)

Comment: Why not? You delete the angular cache and after a fresh rebuild the problem disappears? Sounds like a corrupt cache to me.